# parallelizing tasks in Luigi Orchestrator

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, orchestration, luigi

I defined three tasks `T1`, `T2`, and `T3`, and then a task `T4` as follows:

```
class T4(luigi.Task)
    def requires(self):
        return [T1(), T2(), T3()]
```

Is there a natural way to tell Luigi that I want these tasks `T1`, `T2`, and `T3` to be executed in parallel?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on what dependencies T1, T2 and T3 have. If they haven't another task as a common dependency, you can just run your task specifying `--workers=3` and [Luigi will run each task in a separate worker](http://luigi.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/luigi.interface.html?highlight=workers#luigi.interface.core.workers).

Comment: Can this be set through the luigi.cfg as well?